# Using Pandas to do SIMPLE Backtesting: using until

Tags: python, pandas, finance, back-testing

I have a panda df with a date time index from 1990-2015.

It has columns with an adj close of the S&P 500, a FOR (Financial Obligation Ratio), a PE ratio, and so on and so forth. I've created graphs to look at relationships between the different ratios and market. I'm now trying to backtest an investment strategy. I've done some of this in Quantopian but never on my own and am a newbie to pandas.

The first two columns of my table look like this:

[image]

I've messed around with some of the code but don't know how to do it. The idea is the following: Invest a starting portfolio of $1,000,000 the first month the FOR drops below 16.5. Ride the S&P until the FOR hits 16.5, sell. Buy back when it drops back below again. I think that I would need to use a while statement

```
for idx in df.index:
    if df['Financial Obligation Ratio'].loc[idx]<16.5:

       print idx, df['Adj Close'].loc[idx]
```

This prints all time periods that I would want the $$ invested. Is there a way to use "while" along with "next idx" to make this program successful

Comment: You can remove all of the financial-domain content from the question. This is about conditionally retrieving a portion of a dataframe and should be worded as such.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
            Adj Close    FOR
date
1990-01-09     329.07  16.23
1990-01-08     329.07  16.92

In [22]: df[df['FOR'] < 16.5]
Out[22]:
            Adj Close    FOR
date
1990-01-09     329.07  16.23

In [23]:
```

Comment: That works for finding dates that would be acceptable; however it doesn't help with moving forward until it hits the first break point as to when it is >16.5. Rather it would just jump to the next point in time where it is <16.5.

Comment: Granted, you can see the gap in the time continuum. Yet I still don't see it as an effective way to completely back-test the idea. It seems as though I'm at the same blocking point I was at before.